# Why Parameters passing in URL automatically after submit a form

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api, url-parameters

I am using mvc 4 having 1 view which have a simple HTML form to add employee data in table using web api method ajax call & using Visual Studio 2013.

In code i am not passing any parameter in url but its showing after submit the form & my insert operation working fine.But however i am not able to find the 
cause of parameter in url like below snippet.
So how can i remove this url parameter any trick?

```
http://localhost:1306/AddEmployees?Add_Position_Territory_Region=8&Employee_ID=640488&Add_Position_City=8&Add_Employee_Name=Sanjay+Shivhar+Nakate&Employee+Start+Date=2018-03-14&Add_Position_Cease_Date=2018-03-27&Add_Position_FTE=8&Add_Position_FTE_WM+=8&Add_Currency=8&Add_Position_FTE_SU=8&Add_salary=8&Add_Position_FTE_Total=8&Add_Bouns=8&Add_Incentive=8
```

my snipeet code of the view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("body").on("click", "#AddEmploye", function () {

        var _employee = {};
        _employee.EMPLOYEE_ID = $("#ID_Employee_ID").val();  //*
        _employee.MAX_FTE = $("#ID_Add_Position_FTE").val();//*
        _employee.FTEMW = $("#ID_Add_Position_FTE_WM").val();//*
        _employee.FTESU = $("#ID_Add_Position_FTE_SU").val();//*
        _employee.TOTALFTE = $("#ID_Add_Position_FTE_Total").val();//*

        _employee.EMPLOYEE_ID = $("#ID_Employee_ID").val();//*
        _employee.COUNTRY_ID = $("#Add_Position_Country").val(); //*
        _employee.REGION = $("#ID_Add_Position_Territory_Region").val();  //*
        _employee.CITY = $("#ID_Add_Position_City").val();  //*
        _employee.MARKET_ID = null; //$("#").val(); //No field in form
       // _employee.OTHER_LOCATION = null //$("#").val();  //No field in form

        _employee.CATEGORY_ID = null;// $("#").val();  //No field in form
        _employee.CURRENCY = $("#ID_Add_Currency").val(); //*
        _employee.SALARY = $("#ID_Add_salary").val();//*
        _employee.BONUS = $("#ID_Add_Bouns").val();//*
        _employee.SALES_INCENTIVE = $("#ID_Add_Incentive").val();//*
        _employee.AUXILIARY = null; // $("#ID_Add_Bouns").val();  //No field in form
        _employee.EMPLOYEE_ID = $("#ID_Employee_ID").val();
        _employee.ACTIVE_STATUS = 1 //$("#").val();  //No field in form ** 1

        _employee.POSITION_TITLE_ID = $("#Add_Employee_Title").val(); //*
        _employee.MANAGER_REPORT_TO_ID = null; //$("#").val(); //No field in form
        _employee.POS_CC_ID = $("#Add_Position_Cost_Centre").val(); //*
        _employee.PLAN_START_DATE = $("#ID_Employee_Start_Date").val();  //*
        _employee.CEASE_DATE = $("#ID_Add_Position_Cease_Date").val();
        _employee.COST_CENTERE_ID = $("#Add_Position_Cost_Centre").val();
        _employee.SO_NAME_ID = null; // $("#").val();  //No field in form
        _employee.SAP_CC_ID = null; // $("#").val(); //No field in form
        _employee.DIV_CC_ID = null; // $("#").val(); //No field in form
        _employee.EMPLOYEE_ID = $("#ID_Add_Incentive").val();

        _employee.EMPLOYEE_ID = $("#ID_Employee_ID").val(); //*

        _employee.JOB_FAMILY_GENERIC_ID = null; //$("#").val();  //No field in form
        _employee.JOB_GROUP_ID = null; //$("#").val();  //No field in form
        //_employee.APPROVED_PERIOD = null; //$("#").val();   //No field in form
       // _employee.APPROVED_DATE = null; // $("#").val();   //No field in form
       // _employee.VALIDATION = null; // $("#").val();   //No field in form
       // _employee.PEOPLE_MANAGER = $("#ID_Add_Incentive").val();
       // _employee.POSITION_ID_UK = null; // $("#").val(); //No field in form
        _employee.EMP_ACTIVE_STATUS_TF = 1 //$("#ID_Add_Incentive").val(); //No field in form **
        _employee.JOB_STATUS_TYPE = $("#ID_Add_job_status").val();
        // _employee.JOB_TYPE = null; // $("#ID_Add_Incentive").val();
       // _employee.HEY_LEVEL = null; //$("#").val();  //No field in form

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            // url: "/api/ManageEmployees/AddEmployeesMethod",
            url: "/api/Employee/AddEmployeesMethod",
            data: JSON.stringify(_employee),
            // data: '{" DepartmntName": "' + DepartmntName +'"," DateCreated":"' + DateCreated + '", " DateModified ":"'+ DateModified +'"," IsDeleted":"' + IsDeleted +'", "ParentID":"' + ParentID + '", "Icon": "' + Icon + '", "Paren":"' +  Paren +'" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                alert("success" + r);
                       },
            failure: function (r) {
                alert(r.responseText);
            },
        });
    });

    </script>

    <form class="form-style-9">
        <ul>

            <li>
                <h3>
                    Manage Employee
                </h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                @*<div>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="new" checked> New
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="replaced"> Replaced
                        <select id="Add_Position_Market_Country" class="field-style field-split align-right slide-left-select-box"></select>
                        @*<input type="text" name="field2" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="Market*" />
                    </div>*@
                <h4>
                    Add Employee
                </h4>
            </li>
            <li>
                <select id="Add_job_ID" class="field-style field-split align-left" required></select>
                <select id="Add_Position_Country" class="field-style field-split align-right slide-left-select-box">
                    <option value="">Select Add Country</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <select id="Add_Employee_Title" class="field-style field-split align-left" required></select>
                <input type="text" id="ID_Add_Position_Territory_Region" name="Add_Position_Territory_Region" class=" field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="Territory / Region" />
            </li>

            <li>
                <input type="text" id="ID_Employee_ID" name="Employee_ID" class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="Employee ID" />
                @*<input type="text" name="Add_Position_CC" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="Position CC" />*@

                <input type="text" id="ID_Add_Position_City" name="Add_Position_City" class=" field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="City" />
            </li>

            <li>
                <input type="text" id="ID_Add_Employee_Name" name="Add_Employee_Name" class=" field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="Add Employee Name" />

                <input type="date" id="ID_Employee_Start_Date" name="Employee Start Date" class=" field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="Employee Start Date" />

            </li>
            <li>
                <select id="ID_Add_job_status" class="field-style field-split align-left">
                    <option value="0">--Select job Status--</option>
                    <option value="1">Permanent</option>
                    <option value="2">Temporary</option>
                </select>
                <input type="date" id="ID_Add_Position_Cease_Date" name="Add_Position_Cease_Date" class=" field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="Employee Cease Date" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="text" id="ID_Add_Position_FTE" name="Add_Position_FTE" class=" field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="FTE " />

                <select id="Add_Position_Cost_Centre" class="field-style field-split align-right slide-left-select-box"></select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="text" id="ID_Add_Position_FTE_WM" name="Add_Position_FTE_WM " class=" field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="FTE WM " />

                <input type="text" id="ID_Add_Currency" name="Add_Currency" class=" field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="Currency" />

            </li>

            <li>
                <input type="text" id="ID_Add_Position_FTE_SU" name="Add_Position_FTE_SU" class=" field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="FTE SU" />

                <input type="text" id="ID_Add_salary" name="Add_salary" class=" field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="Salary" />

            </li>
            <li>


                <input type="text" id="ID_Add_Position_FTE_Total" name="Add_Position_FTE_Total" class=" field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="FTE Total" />

                <input type="text" id="ID_Add_Bouns" name="Add_Bouns" class=" field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="Bouns" />

            </li>

            <li>
                <input type="text" id="ID_Add_Incentive" name="Add_Incentive" class=" field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="Incentive" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="AddEmploye"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You handling the click event of your submit button, and not cancelling the default submit, therefore you make an ajax call to submit **plus** you are also making the default submit of the form, which is a GET, therefore the values of the form controls are added to the query string and posted back to you GET method.

Change the script to cancel the default event

```
$("body").on("click", "#AddEmploye", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ....
```